# How would i redirect to the different webpages with certain time interval

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

// when i create this html page it is just redirecting to the first url and how would i  redirect to the next url after five minutes and i cannot make any changes to the urls all i can change is only this webpage.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>I moved!!!</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5;URL=http://url1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="300;URL=http://url2">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="300;URL=http://url3">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="300;URL=http://url4">
</HEAD>

<BODY>

Your browser should automatically take you there in 5 seconds. If it doesn't please go     to http://my.newplace.com/

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

could you please let me know. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should have some data stored persistently across redirects, like store them in [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie). This cookie should contain data that indicates which pages have already been used for redirects. For a more fine-grained control, use JS instead.

This pseudocode should help you

```
var urls = [
      {url:'example.com',time:180000},
      {url:'example2.com',time:190000},
      ... and so on
    ]
  , indexToUse = readCookie('nextIndex') || 0
  ;

setTimeout(function{
  setCookie('nextIndex',indexToUse++);    //set the next index
  window.location = urls[indexToUse].url; //redirect page
},urls[indexToUse].time);
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph for the reply,  I have used that code but with the time interval of 10 and 20 seconds but it didn't do anything , here is the code     <HEAD>
    <TITLE>I moved!!!</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
var urls = [
      {url:'http://www.google.co.uk/',time:10},
      {url:'http://www.google.co.uk/',time:20},
    ]
  , indexToUse = readCookie('nextIndex') || 0
  ;

setTimeout(function{
  setCookie('nextIndex',indexToUse++);    //set the next index
  window.location = urls[indexToUse].url; //redirect page
},urls[indexToUse].time); 
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

Comment: @Shashank because the code provided was pseudocode. The logic is there, but `readCookie` and `setCookie` aren't actually real functions. You have to implement them yourself or use an equivalent function from some framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is now way for a page to tell the browser to do something after it has left the original page.

The instruction to redirect to the third page would have to come from the second page, not the first page.

---

You could implement something with frames, so that the page giving the instruction to redirect is never left, but that is rather icky and won't place nice with framebusters.

---

You might want to investigate writing a browser extension to do this instead.

Answer (score 0):

After the first meta you are on page url1 so you need there to put the next meta.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of this working is using AJAX and loading the pages in a frame. But the URL in the address bar won't change, you'll always be on your initial page unless a meta refresh were to happen after all the AJAX requests were done.

But I believe this is your only solution if you were to not go the browser plugin route, or put meta redirects on the other URLs (which I think is something you might not be after, but I don't know the scope of your project).